# The Difference Between MousEventArgs.Location and Cursor.Position

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't understand why [Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) is different from [MouseEventArgs.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.location.aspx),  they should be the same, don't they?

**Edit: The answer seems to suggest that `Cursor.Position== PointToScreen(MouseEventArgs.Location)`, but my testing indicates otherwise.**

Comment: when you doing the test, make sure the mouse is not moving at that moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MouseEventArgs.Position is the mouse cursor position *relative to the control during the event*, **at the time of the event**.

Cursor.Position is the **current** mouse cursor position *relative to the desktop*.

Comment: This is *the* answer I am seeking for; if you are running in a debugger, and you set the control size to be the screen size, the two can differ, and this was what confused me.

Comment: even the control size is the screen size, but the client size is not the screen size.

Comment: I either don't understand the answer, or it is incorrect. Made a simle form with a button and labels with information about discussed values. Pressed a button and then didn't move mouse. Got in the tace labels on the form: Cursor.Position = {X=159,Y=246}, e.Location = {X=11,Y=6}, PointToScreen(e.Location) = {X=69,Y=86}.

Comment: Since I didn't move mouse between the button press and the information output, "time of the event" must not have mattered.

Comment: Bear in mind that `PointToScreen` and `PointToClient` are relative to the control you called them on.  So `Form.PointToScreen()` will not be the same as `Form1.Button1.PointToScreen()`

Answer (score 1):

I think Cursor.Position is relative to the desktop, whereas MouseEventArgs.Location is relative to the control that fired the event

Comment: My testing indicates that `PointToScreen(MouseEventArgs.Position)` is not equaled to `Cursor.Position`.

Answer (score 1):

MouseEventArgs.location gives you the cursor position **relative to the control during the event**.

Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position gives you the cursor position **relative to the desktop.**

Obviously, these two need not be and are not same. The latter can be used without an event as such too unlike MouseEventArgs.Location

Comment: My testing indicates that `PointToScreen(MouseEventArgs.Position)` is not equaled to `Cursor.Position`.

Comment: That's because MouseEventArgs.Position is the mouse position at the time of the event and Cursor.Position is the current position.

Answer (score 0):

MouseEventArgs.Position is relative to the **client rectangle** of the control, Cursor.Position is in screen coordinate.

Comment: My testing indicates that `PointToScreen(MouseEventArgs.Position)` is not equaled to `Cursor.Position`.